# disable the past date and month using full calendar

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

How to disable the past date and the past month using full calendar in select option I tried out with this function in full calendar

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
  var check = $.fullCalendar.moment(start).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  var today = $.fullCalendar.moment(new Date()).format('DD-MM-YYYY');
  if (check >= today) {

  }
}
```

but not working, it disables next month also. if it possible in javascript? also it fine.[Demo link](http://jsfiddle.net/sedhurabe/x7ts49kd/9/)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some googled code snippet.

you can add this code in your select function.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
var check = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start,'yyyy-MM-dd');
var today = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(),'yyyy-MM-dd');
if(check < today)
{
    // Previous Day. 
}
else
{
    // Right Date
}
```

},

Comment: I tried with this also it's not working fine, In this case, it will block all past date. It will enable from current date only if I go to next month it will not work. for example, today date is 27/4/2017 means next month also selectable from this date only

Comment: That seems to work perfectly well. Out of curiosity, what are you using to run the javascript on all these engines? Got everything set-up or some kind of tool?

Answer (score 0):

Your condition totally works.

```
select: function(start, end, allDay) {
      var check = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(start, 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      var today = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(new Date(), 'yyyy-MM-dd');
      if (check >= today) {
      // True conditions
      }
}
```

Please check this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Geethu_Jose/x7ts49kd/)

Comment: Try using a stable version. Try  FullCalendar v1.5.3

Comment: if i change to V1.5.3 version Sum functionality will not work

Comment: Sum functionality? Cn you be precise about the requirement?

Comment: Pls, See this http://jsfiddle.net/sedhurabe/x7ts49kd/9/ I had updated the code. From current date, I can able to add an event but for next month I cant able to do, my requirement user should not add an event for past date. he can add an event from new date

Answer (score -3):

You can disabling past date and the past month of a full calendar using minDate attribute of datepicker.

```js
var dateToday = new Date();

$('#visit').datepicker({
    minDate: dateToday
});
```

```html
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.7.2/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://davidwalsh.name/demo/jquery-ui-css/custom-theme/jquery-ui-1.7.2.custom.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<input type='text' id='visit' />
```